# ConfigureServices AddHttpClient how to access custom certificate provider which gets certificate from KeyVault?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I need to register a httpclient that uses my custom config provider to get a certificate.  The issue I am facing is that the custom provider is registered in configure container and is not available until after the service **`.Build()`**. My custom provider gets the cert from key vault.

It would be great if there was a way specify my custom config provider here in **ConfigureServices**, and then have it load the certificate after **`.Build()`**?

I will then access this client using the **`HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("CertificateClient")`**.

Is there a way to do this?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient("CertificateClient")
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(??? my custom provider here ???);
            return handler;
        });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you would get hold of the "custom provider" after the service-provider is built? It's not clear what this means.

Comment: You're trying to intercept the IHttpClientFactory before the underlying socket handler is created and cached, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to the IServiceCollection you can probably get your custom provider by calling `GetRequiredService<T>()`. And if you have more or less standard Microsoft setup code, your `IConfigurationRoot` property is also already set. Maybe you can pass that in.

(EDIT) Example:

```cs
    var myProvider = services.GetRequiredService<MyCustomerProvider>();
    services.AddHttpClient("CertificateClient") {
    ...
```

Comment: Please could you show how to use GetRequiredService in the example above?

Comment: I edited my answer. Is this clear enough?

Comment: `GetRequiredService` is on `IServiceProvider`, not on `IServiceCollection`